# If column E contains text I want to run a formula in the next column

Tags: excel, vba, automation

If column E contains the text 1ST then i want a formula to run in the column next to it(column F). Then i want to do the same with the text CUCA but if this text it needs to use another formula in the column next to if (column F)

Can someone help me with this?

For example

[image: Example]

If in column E is the word "1ST" i want a formula and this formula goes from column F to column AG in the same row. The same if the word is "CUCA" but then the formula is something else as you can see in the picture

Thanks!

For the

```
Sub Runcode()
    Dim strFormulas(1 To 6) As Variant        

    Range("F26").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F27").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F28").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F29").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F30").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F31").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F57").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F58").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F59").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F60").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F61").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F62").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F88").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F89").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F90").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F91").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F92").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F93").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F119").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F120").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F121").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F122").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F123").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F124").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F150").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F151").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F152").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F153").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F154").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F155").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F181").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F182").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
        
    Range("F183").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F184").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F185").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F186").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F212").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F213").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
            
    Range("F214").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"   
    
    Range("F215").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"    
    
    Range("F216").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    
    Range("F217").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"


    strFormulas(1) = "+countbycolor(R2C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    strFormulas(2) = "+countbycolor(R5C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    strFormulas(3) = "+countbycolor(R3C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    strFormulas(4) = "+countbycolor(R4C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    strFormulas(5) = "+countbycolor(R7C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
    strFormulas(6) = "+countbycolor(R6C1,R[-24]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using an If/Else or Select Case series to just determine the appropriate formula?

```
Dim word As String

word = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Text

If word = "1ST" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "Put the formula here"
ElseIf word = "CUCA" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "Another formula here"
End If
```

Then if you want to run it over multiple rows at once you could wrap it in a For loop, like so:

```
Dim word As String, oRow as Range

For Each oRow In Selection.Rows
    word = Cells(oRow.Row, 5).Text

    If word = "1ST" Then
        Cells(oRow.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "Put the formula here"
    ElseIf word = "CUCA" Then
        Cells(oRow.Row, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "Another formula here"
    End If
Next oRow
```

Comment: Doens't seem to work. Perhaps it's better if I show you exactly what I want the code to do.